# Что значит следующая запись?

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
arr = [[[-1 for j in xrange(3)] for i in xrange(4)] for st in xrange(2)]
```

Сам не знаток питона, просто нужно перебить код под другой язык.
Скажите, что значит сия запись?
Я так понимаю, что это 3-х мерный массив, т.е. аналогом на java будет, например

```
int[][][] arr = new int[2][4][?];
```

Вот не пойму, массив какого размера задает: 
    [-1 for j in xrange(3)]

Или как это вообще толковать?

И еще, интересно, как запишется вот эта строчка на java?

```
if not(j == 0 or j == 1 and i == 0)
```

Правильно ли ее вот так переписать?

```
if ( !(j==0 || j==1 && i==0) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее, аналогом будет что-то вроде

```
int [][][] arr = new int [3][4][2];
```

А потом весь массив заполняется -1

Этим кодом

```
[-1 for j in xrange(3)]
```

создается список из 3 элементов типа int и всем им присваивается  значение -1

Comment: да, наверное... только вот вопрос - правильно ли расставлены размеры массивов?
> int [][][] arr = new int [3][4][2];  
  
Разве не так должно быть?

> int [][][] arr = new int [2][4][3];

Comment: Может быть. Я Джаву нехорошо знаю. В С/С++ должно быть как я написал. Идея, что 3 будет размерностью "внутреннего" измерения. А там сами посмотрите в справочниках.

Comment: В этом плане java и c++ похожи..
а что можете скачать по поводу второго вопроса?

Comment: Да вроде бы правильно

Comment: @mikillskeg? а как переписать условие?

Answer (score 0):

Задаётся массив размерностью 2х4х3 заполненный -1. `xrange` - это ленивый итератор для циклов в питоне. Просто питон позволяет заполнять всё это быстро и безболезненно. В Java код выглядел примерно так:

```
for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
  for (j=0;j<=4;j++)
    {
     for(k=0;k<=3;k++)
        { 
         arr[i][j][k]=-1
}}}
```

условие записано правильно